# Insert Pivot Table in a new worksheet AFTER the worksheet with the data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Pivot tables are created in a new worksheet BEFORE the sheet with the actual data. I may understand why it does this (ie, it behaves like you right-click on a sheet and then insert-new-worksheet).

Is anyone aware if you can change this behavior so that when you create a pivot table into a new worksheet, then that worksheet with your pivot appears AFTER (ie, to the right of) your data sheet?

My version is Excel 2016.

Comment: By default, the New Worksheet with PivotTable is created on the left of the orginal Data Sheet.

Comment: You can create a macro that mimics the creation of the pivot table and positions the worksheet wherever you want it. Instead of inserting a pivot table as usual, you would need to run the macro. Seems like a lot of effort to change default behavior though.

Comment: @FlexYourData Thanks, yeah, thought of that and agree that it's a bit beyond the effort I want to perform. I was hoping someone knows of some buried setting within Excel.